# How to hide previous month dates in current Month view in react-big-calender

Tags: reactjs, calendar, react-big-calendar, event-calendar

I'm new to **react-big-calender**. I want to **hide** the **previous month's dates** in the current month's view. Is there any way to remove the previous dates?

My code is below.

```
<Calendar
  // toolbar={false}
  localizer={localizer}
  events={myEventsList}
  startAccessor="start"
  endAccessor="end"
  style={{ height: 800 }}
  eventPropGetter={eventStyleGetter}
  view="month"
/>
```

Event List

I have Attached the image.[image: Calender Image]

**Events with current Month**

```
const eventLists = [
  {
    "title": "Event 6",
    "start": "2024-02-01T12:00",
    "end": "2024-02-01T13:00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Event 7",
    "start": "2024-02-03T13:00",
    "end": "2024-02-03T14:00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Event 8",
    "start": "2024-02-05T14:00",
    "end": "2024-02-05T15:00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Event 9",
    "start": "2024-02-07T15:00",
    "end": "2024-02-07T16:00"
  },
]
```

[image]

Comment: What is myEventsList passed as props? Did you try filtering out the data of current month?

Comment: Yes, when I use the current month event. The events are not listed in the calendar but the previous dates are still visible. I have attached the image and event list object.

Comment: I was able to filter out events. Here's what I tried.
```javascript
  const filteredEvents = events.filter((event) => {
    const eventDate = new Date(event.start)
    return eventDate.getMonth() !== 3 // March is month 2 (0-indexed)
  })
return(<Calendar events={filteredEvents}/>)
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it will not hide the previous dates. Those dates are still visible

Answer (score 0):

In the Month view, dates outside of the current month get a class of `rbc-off-range`. To remove the display of the 'date' from those cells you could apply an override class.

```
.rbc-off-range {
  > a {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

As you've already seen, this will still put any `events` on those cells, so it is up to you to programmatically remove them.